# Help needed: Need to run reports to find information on number of members during a specific year

Tags: civimember

Good morning,

I'm a program assistant at the NH Public Health Association, and we need to determine the following data:

1. Number of current (as of a certain date within a year; e.g., February 26, 2019) members of NHPHA
2. Number of members at any time during a specific year (e.g., 2019)

We have tried to use the Reports function to determine these data, without success. Can anyone explain how to do this? Please let us know if there are specific filters we should be using. We appreciate any help anyone could give us. Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,
Jess

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: also try the [nz.co.fuzion.historicmembershipdata extension](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.historicmembershipdata)

Try the [Membership Churn](https://civicrm.org/extensions/membership-churn-reports) extension otherwise

1/ I think you can get via

Adv Search

Set Start Date to < Feb 26 2019

Set End Date to > Feb 26 2019

2/ might be a bit trickier but I suggest using Search Builder and something like

Set Start Date > Jan 1 2019 to Dec 31 2019

OR

Set End Date to > Jan 1 2019 to Dec 31 2019

EDIT: you may need to also exclude Memberships that are 'old' ones which you may be able to do via Memb Status

Comment: Follow-up question, Pete: Using the search filters, how do I search for specifically "Set Start Date to < Feb 26 2019" or "Set End Date to > Feb 26 2019"? I mean, what exactly do I put in the "Choose Date Range" fields?

Comment: for the first example in the Start Date you would leave the 'from' field blank, and put the desired date in the To. so it says, show me all results that started before date x. then in the End date field you say 'show me all results where the End Date is 'after'' hence you put the date in the 'from' and nothing in the 'to'.

Comment: hoping my logic is hte right way round. not looking at Adv Search as i wrote that. also beware. you may need to set the Search Results (top left?) to show data as Memberships rather than Contacts

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for your help.